# How can I find the shortes path on square prism?

Tags: geometry

My boss ask us a geometry question a few hours ago, but we can't find a solution at all..

We have a square prism that long edge is 12 cm and short (base) edges are 4 cm.

[image]

We have 2 points (*A* and *B*). And these are 0,5 cm away from the nearest egde (blue lines) and these points extensions divide two equal pieces (2 cm - 2 cm) their nearest edges.

The question is; Find a way to *A* to *B* smaller than **16cm**..

**The rule is**; the way can't use inside of the prism, only can use surface of the prism.

First of all, for finding the shortest path, I tried to open the prism like;

[image]

Even with that way, |AB| will be more than 16 cm..

Is there any solution for <16 cm?

Note: I tagged the question with only [geometry](/questions/tagged/geometry) tag. So, please feel free to update it..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several different ways to unfold the net of the prism. Let me refer to the figure in the question.

Unfold the prism so that the left end is attached to the bottom face and the right end is attached to the top face. This gives a transverse distance of $2+4+2 = 8$ and a longitudinal distance of $0.5 + 12 + 0.5 = 13$. Pythagorean theorem then gives the straight-line distance as $\sqrt{233}\approx 15.264$.

Try [this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3iTIg.jpg) for the picture.

Comment: I'd upload a picture, but the image service seems to be down for now.

Comment: @SonerGönül It still says "Cannot connect to imgur" for me. I'll try tomorrow.

Comment: @SonerGönül I drew the image in paint so I don't have a link for you. It's not too difficult to visualize, do you understand the description I gave in the answer?

Comment: @SonerGönül I linked to an uploaded image. Does that make it clearer?